# Retrieve lines of a text that contain a certain string only in the end and not somewhere in between

Tags: text, grep, find, pattern-matching

I have a text file of taxonomic assignation of bacterias that looks like this ( the numbers indicate the different bacterias):

```
1130952 k__Bacteria; p__Acidobacteria; c__Acidobacteriia; o__Acidobacteriales; f__Acidobacteriaceae; g__Edaphobacter; s__modestum
555445  k__Bacteria; p__Firmicutes; c__Clostridia; o__Clostridiales; f__Lachnospiraceae; g__Clostridium; s__fimetarium
325910  k__Bacteria; p__Firmicutes; c__Clostridia; o__Clostridiales; f__Ruminococcaceae; g__; s__
744205  k__Bacteria; p__Proteobacteria; c__Deltaproteobacteria; o__; f__; g__; s__
```

Many of the bacterias don´t have the classification down to specie level, so they lack information : "s__". I would like to see the bacterias that have that information (as in the two bacterias above, one being "s__modestum" and the other "s__fimetarium"). 
I am using a mac terminal (Mac OS X 10.9.5) and tried,

```
grep -v "s__" file
```

but since all the assignation contain `s__` I get noting back (it excludes them all I guess..).

I have tried using `*` at the end as in `s__*` but it doesn't work either.

What I would like is to apply a command and get the line and a count of bacterias with the species assignation.

```
1 1130952 k__Bacteria; p__Acidobacteria; c__Acidobacteriia; o__Acidobacteriales; f__Acidobacteriaceae; g__Edaphobacter; s__modestum
1 555445    k__Bacteria; p__Firmicutes; c__Clostridia; o__Clostridiales; f__Lachnospiraceae; g__Clostridium; s__fimetarium
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ask `grep` to match any character after `s__` not being end of line (expressed with `$`):

```
$ grep 's__[^$]' file
1130952 k__Bacteria; p__Acidobacteria; c__Acidobacteriia; o__Acidobacteriales; f__Acidobacteriaceae; g__Edaphobacter; s__modestum
555445  k__Bacteria; p__Firmicutes; c__Clostridia; o__Clostridiales; f__Lachnospiraceae; g__Clostridium; s__fimetarium
```

To get the count of lines matching this condition, you need to use something like `awk` to store the counter values into an array:

```
$ awk '/s__[^$]/ {a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) print a[i], i}' file
1 555445  k__Bacteria; p__Firmicutes; c__Clostridia; o__Clostridiales; f__Lachnospiraceae; g__Clostridium; s__fimetarium
1 1130952 k__Bacteria; p__Acidobacteria; c__Acidobacteriia; o__Acidobacteriales; f__Acidobacteriaceae; g__Edaphobacter; s__modestum
```

---

To make it check this is appearing at the very end of the file, we need some extra checks:

```
grep -E 's__[^ $]+$' file
awk '/s__[^ $]+$/ {a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) print a[i], i}' file
```

They check that after `s__` there is a set of at least one character not being space or end of line. And then, end of line.

---

#### Update

> Thank you it worked great! Is there a way I can sum up all the lines
>   so I could know how many counts I have in total of the non "s__"? – 
>   Isa

Sure, just add `print length(a)` to see how many elements the array has:

```
$ awk '/s__[^ $]+$/ {a[$0]++} END {for (i in a) print a[i], i; print length(a)}' a
1 555445  k__Bacteria; p__Firmicutes; c__Clostridia; o__Clostridiales; f__Lachnospiraceae; g__Clostridium; s__fimetarium
1 1130952 k__Bacteria; p__Acidobacteria; c__Acidobacteriia; o__Acidobacteriales; f__Acidobacteriaceae; g__Edaphobacter; s__modestum
2
```

Comment: Thank you it worked great! Is there a way I can sum up all the lines so I could know how many counts I have in total of the non "s__"?